# Pixel control in terminal with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just getting to grips with modern programming having previously dabbled in QBasic as a child. In QBasic I could run in DOS and write a program which would control individual pixels on the screen. I was able to do quite a lot graphically with this without having to worry about windows etc.

I've done quite a few Google searches for similar things in Python and I cannot find anything which allows me to do this in the Terminal. I'm running Lubuntu and Raspbian respectively on my notebook and my Raspberry Pi Model B. I've checked the curses module and this seems to be limited to displaying character in character cells, which seems to be different from manipulating specific pixels on screen.

Am I right in thinking I'm going to have to work in a GUI/X environment in order to be able to turn individual pixels on or off?d

Comment: Do you want to manipulate pixels only in the terminal, or in the outside GUI as well?

Comment: Just in the terminal. I'd quite like to be able to run this in the Linux terminal without launching the GUI at all. My R-Pi boots to terminal and I rarely have a mouse attached to it.

Comment: By *far* most terminals are indeed character based. It is their basic operation mode, and what they are designed for. From a program's view, a terminal is something that can receive and send characters only – even plain "text color" is *highly* optional.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a GUI to do anything with individual pixels.

Comment: Cross-SE duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/97542. Note that the answers there assume a high-end desktop attached, not a Raspberry Pi.